# Instantiate a class from text file

Tags: java, file-io, instantiation

I have a text file with names, phone numbers, and employee ID's.

Example:

```
Chris Cotton
5555555555
CCOTTON

Joshua Trammell
5555555555
JTRAMMELL
```

And I have a class called Employee with a constructor that takes Name, Phone number, and ID.

How can I use that text file to instantiate the employee class for each record in my text file, using the employee id as the object name?

```
package com.evolution.model;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private String employeeId;

    public Employee(String name, int phoneNumber, String employeeId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Break the problem down into testable parts. 1. Open up a file for reading. 2. Make sure you can figure out how to read a "record" as you have defined it, and can present this record as the right data for consumer code. 3. Write some code that takes three pieces of info and creates an Employee object. 4. Write some code that pulls all of this together to open the file, create the objects and do something with them, and then close the file. As it stands, this is a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: "using the employee id as the object name" You should _really_ explain what you mean by this. It is unlikely you actually need to create an object that is referenced by a variable that is named after some data you fetch from a file. Maybe you mean you want to use the employee ID as a key of some sort for a database?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line, and can maintain three consecutive lines in an array and the moment you capture three lines, you can construct the employee Object using its constructor the way I have shown in my main method.

Here is a sample code you can use. Just to be safe, I have changed data type for phoneNumber from `int` to `String` because a phone number may or may not contain only numbers. But if you are sure that your phone numbers will only contain digits that too not starting with zeroes, you can write `Integer.parseInt(fileLines.get(i + 1))` instead of just `fileLines.get(i + 1)` in the constructor creation call in for loop.

Here is a sample code for same,

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String employeeId;

    public Employee(String name, String phoneNumber, String employeeId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("name: %s, phoneNumber: %s, employeeId: %s",
                new Object[] { name, phoneNumber, employeeId });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("emp.txt"));) {
            String line = null;

            int counter = 0;
            String[] lineObject = new String[3];
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                if (line.length() == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                lineObject[counter++] = line;
                if (counter == 3) {
                    counter = 0;
                    Employee employee = new Employee(lineObject[0], lineObject[1], lineObject[2]);
                    System.out.println(employee);
                    // employee.dowhatever();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When executed, this program prints following output,

```
name: Chris Cotton, phoneNumber: 5555555555, employeeId: CCOTTON
name: Joshua Trammell, phoneNumber: 5555555555, employeeId: JTRAMMELL
```

Comment: Reading the entire file into memory is both unnecessary and not scalable.

Comment: @VGR: Well, I am aware about that which is why I tried using Files.lines() method which lazily reads the lines from file. But the information required to construct one object was lying in multiple lines so I didn't go for a relatively complex solution. Although of course I know how to avoid loading all file data into memory, but just didn't put much effort as OP hasn't mentioned anything about huge data files. Is that really a strong reason to downvote the answer?

Comment: @VGR: I have updated my answer using plain old BufferedReader way of reading file. Hope this looks fine. However, I would love to learn from you, using Files.lines() method to read file and construct Employee object using those three parameters using stream and lambda expressions and avoiding storing data in memory. Thank You.

Comment: @VGR: Still waiting for your reply :)

Comment: You are over-complicating things by reading only one line at a time.  Why not just read one line, and if it’s not blank, immediately read two more lines, then create an Employee object from those three values?

Comment: @VGR: What you are suggesting is just another way of doing it (of course there are many ways of doing something). I was expecting to see a `Files.lines()` solution with usage of streams and lamda. I am still new to Java8 lambda and streams stuff... so was expecting you to show something like that.

Comment: Streams and lambdas are fun, but they are not the best solution for every problem.

Comment: @VGR: Forget best, I just want it for academic purposes only :) I really want to see how it can be done in `Files.lines()` method while reading the data lazily from file.

Comment: That would be an interesting exercise, but would not be a good answer to the question.

Comment: @VGR: Answer to this question I think I have already given. What I was really looking for is a solution to this using `Files.lines()` method, which at the moment I can't think how to do. I am still a very beginner in Java 8 streams and lambdas. This is the whole reason of writing you these messages and following you up to see how such a solution can be done. I will learn something good and new from you, if you help and provide a solution. Meanwhile you will earn lots of upvotes too and first would be mine :)

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Comment: @VGR: Well, this question is already there which is eagerly seeking a **lambda streams lazily read a file** solution :) And the solution would really be an elegant solution, needing lesser codes whilst still being performant.